# Как убить поток с бесконечным циклом и обработкой ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#

Есть ли способ убить поток, в котором отрабатывает такой метод?

```
public static void M()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, до тех пор пока не выполнится RestAbort, поток убить нельзя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться атрибутом `SecurityPermission`.

Например, при таком подходе происходит облом на попытке выполнить `Thread.ResetAbort();`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    thread.Abort();
    while (thread.IsAlive)
    {

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Готово");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, ControlThread = false)]
public static void SomeMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }
    }
}
```

Однако, смерть потока с необработанным исключением означает смерть всего приложения => нужно обернуть все в глобальный `try/catch` вокруг метода из ненадежного источника.

А вот такой поток не умирает:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    thread.Abort();
    while (thread.IsAlive)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        thread.Abort();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Готово");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, ControlThread = false)]
public static void SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.ResetAbort();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("2");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Делая `ResetAbort` поток обламывается, но обрабатывает исключение и крутится в бесконечном цикле. Многократные попытки вызвать `Abort` из главного потока не срабатывают. Поток продолжает жить...

Хотя, есть другое более правильное решение- домены приложений (`AppDomain`), который как раз используются для кода из ненадежного источника.

Если мы загрузим небезопасный код в отдельный домен, то он успешно сможет прерваться при выгрузке домена, чихая на `Thread.ResetAbort();`:

```
public class TestClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("1");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.ResetAbort();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            Console.WriteLine("2");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
        var t=(TestClass)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(TestClass).Assembly.FullName, typeof(TestClass).FullName);
        Task.Run(() => t.SomeMethod());
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Если верить Рихтеру, то по такому принципу работает механизм `SQL CLR` в `MS SQL SERVER`, который не дает сборке вызвать `Thread.RestAbort()`.

Answer (score 4):

Способ принудительно завершить поток есть, хотя MS его не рекомендует как слишком грубый.
Это функция `WinAPI` [TerminateThread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread).
В качестве параметра она требует хэндл потока, его можно получить сначала узнав `ID` потока через [ManagedThreadId](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid?view=netframework-4.7.2), а потом по `ID` получить хэндл функцией `WinAPI` [OpenThread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread).

Comment: А приложение будет жить при смерти потока или умрет из-за необрабатываемого исключения?

Comment: @iluxa1810, будет жить конечно, с чего бы предложению помирать. Разве что главный поток завершить. Необработанное исключение тут никаким боком, при завершении потока все данные потока очищаются (немного упрощенно, конечно)

Comment: ManagedThreadId это не ID потока ОС. ID потока ОС можно получить например через через WINAPI GetCurrentThreadId

Comment: Так же есть доп. нюансы: Убитый поток таким образом будет висеть со статусом Runing и IsAlive=true.

Comment: @iluxa1810, насчет ID спасибо за дополнение, я думал что managed code просто использует оригинальный ID потока (хотя непонятно почему нет). А насчет нюансов - да, потому MS и не рекомендует. Очень грубый способ, его стоит использовать только когда очень надо, а нормальный вариант недоступен.

Comment: Где-то писалось, что управляемый поток может менять поток ОС на котором он выполняется https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281697/4244707 . А ManagedId- это что-то стабильное.